# it is for forbidden to do something good for someone who does not acknowledge the good

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, mussar-ethics, middos-character-traits, hakaras-hatov

"it is for forbidden to do something good for someone who does not acknowledge the good"

is this true? what is the source of this? who else holds like this?

at this [site](http://hamodia.com/2015/10/07/hakaras-hatov/) it says:

> Maharal explains (in [Gur Aryeh on Rashi for Bereshit 2:5, s.v. *ve-Ein Makir be-Tovatam*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42841&pgnum=93)), “V’assur laasos tovah l’ish she’ein makir b’tovah — it is forbidden to do something good for someone who doesn’t express gratitude for the good.”

Rabbi Arush seems to say this idea is from the Hazal
["בגן השלום" של הרב שלום ארוש שליט"א, ע"מ 197](http://vitaminim.org/1/index.php?topic=13845.0)

> אמרו חז"ל שאפילו מי שאינו ממש כפוי טובה, רק הוא אינו מכיר בטובה- אסור לעשות לו טובה, ויתרה מזה אמרו, שכל העושה לו טובה הרי הוא כעובד עבודה זרה. נמצא, מי שיודע בעצמו שאינו יודע להכיר טובה, אסור לו לתת לאנשים לעשות לו טובות כי בזה הוא מכשיל אותם בעבודה זרה, ועובר על "לפני עיור לא תיתן מכשול" .

Comment: Is there a source for the quote from the Maharal other than the website says he says it? Also, do you have the page number for "The Garden of Peace" for those who don't understand the Hebrew text?

Comment: @ezra that is what i am asking, all the information i know/found i gave (it is page 197 in the Hebrew version)

Comment: related http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38138&st=&pgnum=127

Comment: @TamirEvan that is an answer another link https://www.sefaria.org/Gur_Aryeh_on_Bereishit.2.5.3 but it is missing the very good footnotes in your link

Comment: I wasn't aware the _Gur Aryeh_ was available on Sefaria, and found the source through searching the Hebrew version on Google (my thanks to [aspaklaria.info](http://www.aspaklaria.info/005_HE/%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94.htm) for the cite). I used HebreBooks because I was more sure to find  a link-able source there. If you prefer the Sefaria link, I have no problem with you replacing it.

Comment: @TamirEvan i link your link more because of the footnote you can bring it an an answer and then i will completely erase it

Comment: so it is not "who doesn’t express gratitude" but who does not recognize the good, because we give tzedoko even if the person does not know who gave it and, but probably only if he  recognizes that what he received is good

Comment: Possibly from כל מי שאין בו דעה אסור לרחם עליו ([here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=33&format=pdf))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring an earlier source for this idea, I'll quote the following from what Rabbeinu Bachya wrote in [Chovas Halevavos 3:10:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart,_Third_Treatise_on_Service_of_God.10.19?with=all&lang=bi)

> ומקום הכילות על האכזרים והפתאים ומי שאינם מכירים את עצמם ולא ערך הטובה עליהם כמ״‎ש (שם ט) יוסר לץ לוקח לו קלון ומוכיח לרשע מומו ואמרו ז״‎ל כל העושה טוב למי שאינו מכירו כאלו זורק אבן למרקוליס
>
> Miserliness is in place towards the cruel and foolish and those who do not recognize themselves, nor the value of the beneficence bestowed on them, as it is said, "He that reproves a scorner gets to himself shame: and he that rebukes a wicked man, it is a blemish to himself" (Prov. 9:7). Our wise men say, **"He who does a favor to an ingrate is like a man who casts a stone to *Markolis*" (A form of idol worship in ancient times).**

Comment: +1 but i will b"n accept it if you find where "our wise men say" this

Comment: Merape Lnefesh seems to say it is https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.133a.51 the Tov Levanan says it is https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Mishlei.26.2 (the commentaries can be found https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart,_Third_Treatise_on_Service_of_God.10.19?with=Commentary&lang=bi )

Comment: (the way i understand it is just like a someone will think that it is a good thing to do to through a stone on an idel, but if it is a Markolis he is wrong (it is forbiden to do it), same is by a someone who does not appresiate the good you think you are doing good by giving it to him but realy it is bad.